# Firefox cache images download

Tags: firefox, caching

How can I open location where all the images are downloaded in firefox?

I am searching for Instagram pictures that are on my HDD.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Answer (score 6):

The cache folder of Firefox (in Windows Vista or newer) is located under `C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[Profile Name]\cache2`. Unfortunately, you can't browse inside the contents directly: here is analysis for the new storage format (`cache2`) , starting from in version FF 27: [Mozilla Firefox Cache Folder Analysis](http://www.acquireforensics.com/blog/mozilla-cache-folder.html)

In order to access Firefox cache files you may either (I suppose you use the latest FF version, 47):

- use this free tool: [MZCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html)

> MZCacheView is a small utility that reads the cache folder of
>   Firefox/Mozilla/Netscape Web browsers, and displays the list of all
>   files currently stored in the cache. For each cache file, the
>   following information is displayed: URL, Content type, File size, Last
>   modified time, Last fetched time, Expiration time, Fetch count, Server
>   name, and more. You can easily select one or more items from the cache
>   list, and then extract the files to another folder, or copy the URLs
>   list to the clipboard.
>   MZCacheView doesn't require any installation process or additional DLL
>   files. Just copy the executable file (MozillaCacheView.exe) to any
>   folder you like, and run it. After you run it, the main window
>   displays the list of files currently stored in the cache of the
>   Mozilla/Firefox profile that you used in the last time. If you want to
>   view the cache of another profile, simply use the 'Select Cache
>   Folder' option (F9), and choose the desired cache folder. You can
>   select one or more cache files from the list, and than export the list
>   into text/html/xml file ('Save Selected Items' option), copy the URL
>   list to the clipboard (Ctrl+U), copy the entire table of cache files
>   (Ctrl+C), and then paste it to Excel or to OpenOffice spreadsheet. You
>   can also extract the actual files from the cache, and save them into
>   another folder, You can do that by using the 'Copy Selected Cache
>   Files To' option (F4).

- Alternatively in FF address bar type `about:cache`:
  click `List Cache Entries` and then search (via <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>) for `instagram` entries;  clicking on each entry you'll get the URL of the original file and a hex dump of the local file from cache. Then you may follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/263382) for converting the hex dump into a working file (you'll need two apps for that: HxD and Scite).

Comment: I'm using the MZCacheView solution. Their website have plenty of examples.